# How to hide a div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to hide the div when user clicks on checkbox but i am unable to do that using this code.

```js
$('input.maxtickets_enable_cb').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
    $(this).next('div.max_tickets').show();

  $('#block').hide(1000);

  else 
    $('div.max_tickets').hide();
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="opwp_woo_tickets">
  <label>Deals</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][0][enable]">
  <div class="max_tickets">
    <input type="text" name="dealprice" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="block">Iqbal</div>
```

Comment: I think your jquery is failing, why dont you add curly braces in your if statement since you want to have more than one line inside.... check your console for errors

Comment: I added your code to a snippet and formatted it properly. You can now see that you have a syntax error with your `if/else` statement

Comment: Well i used curly braces but my first statement in if condition is working but when i put the second statement there then it's not working i just want to show the textbox when user will click on combox box and hide the div and i am able to show the textbox on checkbox click but unable to hide the div because second statement is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Put your if block in curly braces `{}` as it contains more than one statement ... otherwise the `else` is without a preceeding if and hence is an "Unexpected else" ...

```js
$('input.maxtickets_enable_cb').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).next('div.max_tickets').show();

  $('#block').hide(1000);
}
  else {
    $('div.max_tickets').hide();
         $('#block').show(1000); // add this if you would like to use the check box as a toggle !
}
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="opwp_woo_tickets">
  <label>Deals</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][0][enable]">
  <div class="max_tickets">
    <input type="text" name="dealprice" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="block">Iqbal</div>
```

Comment: The explanation was there since I posted the answer .. but that's ok ...

Answer (score -2):

in jquery curly braces is required when you use if-else
without curly braces else is not consider with if statement

and without curly braces only one statement is consider with control statement

Comment: this is not true.

Comment: i think you have to try it

Comment: First point, Javascript .. not jQuery ! If you would like `if .. else` and the if only has one statement after it , then you can do without `{}`... otherwise you need the curly braces around the if block ... if you forget curly braces after else then you might get undesired results, but at least not a basic syntax error....